# Does Istio JWT verification mean I can neglect using Spring Security to protect routes?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, architecture, jwt, istio

A quick thanks and appreciation for your help. The main gist is I am creating a microservice ecosystem and will be using Istio as my service mesh. For the services themselves, I am using Spring Boot. For auth I am using a JWT implementation.

Spring security is the staple for route protection and auth. However, Istio can use its sidecar to deny any request to the service API if the JWT validation fails.

Is there any value to including spring security as an authentication filter if the JWT has already been validated? The services will conduct their business logic based on the info taken from the validated JWT.

Thanks!